# Validar el mes de un arreglo de datos timestamp con php y Laravel5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

En mi controlador traigo la fecha de un elemento con created_at esto me devuelve un arreglo con las fechas en mi base de datos, necesito validar si dentro de este arreglo de datos esta el mes 07 o no. Mi problema es que pru me trae el mes 1 si hago un dd y si traigo el año me trae 1970, me hace la validacion de uno de los elementos del arrglo si en la funcion strto time en el arreglo dates pongo un elemento como dates[0] pero solo uno, necesito que se valide en todos. Este es el codigo que estoy implementando:

```
   public function index()
    {
    $dates = DB::table('stocks')->pluck('created_at');

    foreach($dates as $date){
        $pru = date("m", strtotime($dates)); 
        $pru2 = collect($pru);
        // dd($pru);
        if($pru2->contains('07')){
            dd("si tiene Julio");
        }else{
            dd("no tiene Julio");
        }
    }
    return view('chartjsprueba')->with([
         'stocks', $stocks,
         'fecha', $fecha
         ]);
}
```

Como puede validar el mes en todos los elementos del arreglo $dates?

Answer (score 0):

Se tomo un enfoque diferente para validar el mes de los datos solicitados por usuario, se realizo una consulta para el modelo con whereBetween donde se ingresa en una vista las fechas de inicio y de cierre de corte para los datos solicitados.

```
public function show($id)
{
//fechas insertadas de una vista, son tipo date
   $fecha1 = DB::table('fechas')->pluck('fecha_inicio')->all();
   $fecha2 = DB::table('fechas')->pluck('fecha_fin')->all();
//se convierten en string
   $fecha1 = implode($fecha1);
   $fecha2 = implode($fecha2);
//se vuelven un string de carbon
   $primer_dia = (new Carbon($fecha1))->toDateString();
   $ultimo_dia = (new Carbon($fecha2))->toDateString();
//consulta
   $consumes = consume::where('user_id', $id)
      ->whereBetween('created_at',[$primer_dia,$ultimo_dia])
      ->get();
//retorna la vista con estos datos
   return view('user.consumo.show', [
      'consumes'=>$consumes,
      'fecha1' =>$fecha1,
      'fecha2' =>$fecha2,
   ]);
}
```

Se tuvo que convertir la fecha a string del modo señalado ya que si se hacia directamente no validaba el wherebetween.
Quedo atento a comentarios.